# React Navigation: "Cannot Add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function" when using Custom Navigators

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to make the UI for my app in the below picture:

[My App's UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrXgQ.png)

I follow the instruction of React Navigation to make the [Custom Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html) according to the UI but it doesn't work in Android. The red screen appears with the message "Cannot Add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function". Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import TabAboutScreen from './TabAbout';
import TabMyLessonScreen from './TabMyLesson';
import TabTeacherScreen from './TabTeacher';
import { ScrollView, View, Text } from '../../../components';
import TabNavigator from './TabNavigator';
import TopBar from './TopBar';
import styles from './styles';
import CourseHeader from './CourseHeader';
import theme from '../../../theme';
import i18n from '../../../i18n';

export const CourseDetailStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  TabAbout: TabAboutScreen,
  TabMyLesson: TabMyLessonScreen,
  TabTeacher: TabTeacherScreen,
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'TabAbout',
});

export default class TabCourseDetail extends Component {
  static router = CourseDetailStackNavigator.router;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._handleOnBackButtonPress = this._handleOnBackButtonPress.bind(this);
  }

  _handleOnBackButtonPress() {
    // do something
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TopBar textButton={i18n.t('CMBack')} title={i18n.t('CDCourseDetail')} onPress={this._handleOnBackButtonPress} />
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.scrollContainer}
          stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          alwaysBounceVertical={false}
        >
          <CourseHeader />
          <TabNavigator />
          <View style={styles.test}>
            <CourseDetailStackNavigator navigation={this.props.navigation} />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

My evironment: react-navigation: 2.12.1, react-native: 0.55.4
I found out that the problem was that I put  inside  component by following the document of react navigation. It works well in iOS but doesn't work in Android. 
Have you ever faced this problem. I'm looking forward to your solutions. Best regard.

Comment: Which version of `react` and `react-native` you are using?

Comment: Did you have a component that containing text string that doesn't wrap with `<Text>String</Text>` tag ?

Comment: @RaviRupareliya react: 16.3.1, react-native: 0.55.4

Comment: @arufian I checked all my components and all text string is wrapped with <Text>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not left any commented code in the return method and also have not left any text (string) without Text tag of react native.